# Getters are not visible in other classes

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm learning Java for a week, and now i have a problem, because i want to print all Arraylist in method printArray, but the method don't see getName() and other methods and I don't know how to solve my problem. Thanks a lot for your help.
If you can, please show my what I;m doing wrong.

**Class Positions:**

```
  public class Positions {

        List<Positions> list = new ArrayList<>(15);

        int ageAdd;
        int IDAdd;
        String nameAdd;
        int counter;
        String name;
        int age;
        int ID;

        public Positions(String name, int age, int ID) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.ID = ID;
        }

        public Positions() {
            this("", 0, 0);
        }

//there are methods:
//adding element
//removing element
//changing values
//etc
public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void printArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " : " + " NAME: " + list.getName(i) + " AGE: " + list.getAge(i) + " ID: " list.getID(i));


        }
    }
```

**Class main:**

```
public class ArrayList2
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Positions p = new Positions();
        System.out.println("----LISTA TABLICOWA-----");
        System.out.println("Co chcesz wykonać? ");
        System.out.println("1. Dodac element do listy. ");
        System.out.println("2. Usunac elemnt z listy.");
        System.out.println("3. Wstawić na dowolna pozycje.");
        System.out.println("4. Rozmiar listy.");
        System.out.println("5. Zmienic wartosc na podanym indeksie.");
        System.out.println("6. Wyświetlić listę. ");


       while(true) {
           System.out.println("podaj pozycję: ");
           Scanner ch = new Scanner(System.in);
           int choice= ch.nextInt();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    p.addPosition(); //?
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    p.removePosition();
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    p.setOnAnyPosition();
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    p.ArraySizeShow();
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                {
                    p.changePosition();
                    break;
                }
                case 6:
                {
                    p.printArray();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to call getName() on the elements of the List, not on the List itself

Comment: What do you mean with "the method don't see getName() and other methods"? Do you get an error when you compile or run your code? What is the exact error message and where in the code does the error occur?

Comment: `list.get(i).getName()`

Comment: in Itellij GetName() i coloured red, and there is a comment "Cannot resolve method 'getName(int)'"

Comment: @KamilaNowak that is because those getters don't exist. Not in the List interface, which is where you call them on. In your own class, they don't take parameters, so when calling them on the right type, don't pass a parameter

Comment: @Stultuske I don't understand much, why they don't exist. I thought that all methods in class can be used in all methods in the same class.

Comment: they can, but you are not calling them on an instance of your class, but on an instance of List, and in List, they don't exist. In your code, you pass a parameter ( -> i ), but the getters you have in your class don't accept parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have a problem with the array access:

Instead of using:

```
public void printArray() {
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(i + " : " + " NAME: " + list.getName(i) ...);
   }
}
```

You should use:

```
public void printArray() {
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(i + " : " + " NAME: " + list.get(i).getName() ...);
   }
}
```

because you want to get the name of a specific element, and in OO languages, that usually means calling the method on the object itself.

Ijn your example, you have a list that contains objects that contains a name. So if you want to access the name from the list, you need to first get an element then get his name.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change method with below code. Hope it would help.

```
public void printArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " : " + " NAME: " + list.get(i).getName() + " AGE: " + list.get(i).getAge() + " ID: " list.get(i).getID());


        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You should check the method `getName(i)`: it is not expecting a parameter, you shoulkd change it to `getName()`.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Actually it is copy and paste mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To loop over your list either use

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Positions p = list.get(i);
    System.out.println(i + " : " + " NAME: " + p.getName() + " AGE: " + p.getAge() + " ID: " + p.getID());
}
```

or

```
int index =0;
for (Positions p : list) {
    System.out.println(index++ + " : " + " NAME: " + p.getName() + " AGE: " + p.getAge() + " ID: " + p.getID());
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but instance "p" of Positions is in main, so in my class "Positions" I had an error that compiler can't find "p".

Comment: @KamilaNowak That error is because you cannot reference a variable in another class without having that other class also referenced. But the code in this answer is valid. [ Positions p ] is locally defined in this method. Even if you had a [Positions p] in your Positions class, it would still work as the variable is locally overridden in the method.